# Cython, protected attributes

Tags: attributes, protected, cython

I need to modify a **non-public** attribute of an instance of `C` within another instance.

```
cdef class C:
    cdef C superC

    cdef MakeToSuper(self, C other):
        other.superC    = C
```

`protected` would probably do the trick in C, but how can I achive this in `Cython` ?

Comment: This question needs to be clarified. What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: @fabrizioM A class `C` has 2 instances, *A* and *B*. Their class defines an attribute that should be invisible to any user, but instances of C should be able to see and modifiy this attribute. I thought the piece of code would do it. ^^

Comment: I don't understand too. cdef attribute inside class are public inside Cython context. And they are not accessible in Python. So your snippet is working right ? What more do you want ?

Comment: I want an attribute that can be setted from another instance of `C` but not from any other context.

Comment: Python itself lacks any "protected" behavior - I am not sure if Cython allows this either. The best practice, in some cases, is just to prefix the attribute name with underscore and tell users not to mess with it.

Comment: Thank you. Could you post this as answer so I can mark it as accepted ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tried?

```
_
```

For "do not touch it pls" message (ok, only python programmers will understand it, but its better than none).

There is also

```
__
```

Double underscore is like "private" in Python (but still can be accessed if used proper Python mechanisms).

Go for __ (double underscore), and use some python magic to access it in other instances of your class. It will still be accessible by the same magic from any other python code, but everyone who knows how to bypass it knows also that it is there for a reason.

Comment: Thats the usual way I did it in Python, I thought there may be another way in cython. :) Thanks